# How to find the nth duplicate from an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I was trying to solve the problem.

Basically I need to pick the second duplicate from a character array.

```
Input {'x','y','z','x','y'} output: y
Input { 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b' } Output: b
Input { 'a','a','a','b','a','c','b','a','c','b' } output: b
```

EDIT:

```
Input {'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'} Output: a
```

I have tried writing this piece of code but it fails if the first character repeats itself immediately :( Any help in correcting this?

```
 public static char returnSecondDuplicate(char[] arr)
        {
            if (arr.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("empty input");
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            Char second = '\0';
            int duplicateCount = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Length - 1; i++)
            {

                if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(arr[i]))
                {
                    dictionary.Add(arr[i], 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    duplicateCount++;

                    if (duplicateCount == 2)
                    {
                        second = arr[i];
                    }
                }
            }

            return second;
        }
```

Comment: Your count is just increasing without connection to any particular element

Comment: In your third Input, the ones that begins with { 'a','a','a',.... the second duplicate wouldn't be 'a' ? because it appears duplicated more than 1 time. You want to pick the second repetition but the one that has a different value from the first one ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried to look at .ElementAt(0) and compare if the duplicate is the first duplicate, but somehow was missing some additional check. Still failing to get it via for loops :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are counting the number of total duplicates, rather than the number of duplicates of a single character.

Some linq answers have been presented, but if you want to know how to fix your existing code, you could do something like this:

```
public static char returnSecondDuplicate(char[] arr)
{
    if (arr.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Empty Array passed");
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    char firstDuplicate = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Length - 1; i++)
    {

        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(arr[i]))
        {
            dictionary.Add(arr[i], 1);
        }
        else if (firstDuplicate == '\0')
        {
            firstDuplicate = arr[i];
        }
        else if(arr[i] != firstDuplicate)
        {
            return arr[i];
        }

    }

    return '\0'; //not found
}
```

Basically, you have to keep track of which letter is duplicated first. Once you have that first duplicate, check subsequent ones aren't the same letter. The first duplicate that differs is what you want to return.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve it nicely:

```
var secondDuplicate = input.GroupBy( c => c)
                           .Where( g => g.Count() > 1)
                           .Skip(1)
                           .First()
                           .Key;
```

First you group them, then discount all group with only one element (since they are not duplicates), then take the second one (by skipping the first)

Comment: Considering you do `FirstOrDefault()` and then immediately take the `Key`, you'll still throw an exception if there isn't a second duplicate. You should either change it to `First()` (so it throws a more useful message, earlier) or put in a null check (if having no second duplicate isn't an exceptional scenario).

Comment: Yes, I agree. It should be made a bit more robust to handle those cases where you do not have a second duplicate.

Comment: The code fails for this input {'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'}

The Output should be 'a' in this case as 'b' happens to be the first duplicate and 'a' the second duplicate.

Comment: This won't find the *real* second duplicate i.e. the first char to be matched twice.

Comment: @James and Navyseal - I solved it the way I *actually* thought he wanted to have the result. It wasn't entirely clear if he wanted the first complete duplicate, or the duplicate that started first. Could be argued both ways, but now we know that the OP has clarified, it seems that the logic have to be modified to account for this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic extension method that works for the given cases:

```
public static T GetNthDuplicate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
{
    HashSet<T> hashSet = new HashSet<T>();
    return source.Where(item => !hashSet.Add(item))
                 .Distinct().Skip(n - 1) //one based index
                 .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your original code is you are incrementing *every* time you see a duplicate character, however, you don't detect whether it is already been taken into account. A simple change would be to use a list (instead of an integer) to keep track of the duplicates.

Also, another small enhancement (in my opinion) would be to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` because you only want to iterate until some condition is met so it seems a better fit e.g.

```
public static char returnSecondDuplicate(char[] arr)
{
    if (arr.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Empty Array passed");
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    var duplicates = new List<char>();
    Char second = '\0';
    int i = 0;

    while (duplicates.Count != 2 && dictionary.Count != arr.Length)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(arr[i]))
            dictionary.Add(arr[i], 1);
        else if (!duplicates.Contains(arr[i]))
            duplicates.Add(arr[i]); // only add duplicates once (ignoring any duplicate duplicates!)

        second = duplicates.Count == 2 ? arr[i] : second;
        i++;
    }

    return second;
}
```

[See it running](http://ideone.com/PJ8tiL)